# Prove a set is a perfect set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

For $x\in [0,1)$, let $x=0.x_1x_2x_3...$ denote the decimal expansion of $x$ with the minimal number of $9's$. A perfect set is defined to be a set that is closed and has no isolated points.

(a)Suppose A is a subset of the positive integers $N$ such that $N\setminus A$ is inﬁnite. Let $C_A=\{x\in[0,1):x=0.x_1x_2x_3... \ \mbox{with}\  x_n=9 \ \mbox{iff}\  n\in A\}$.Prove that $C_A$ is a perfect set.
(b)Show that [0, 1] is the union of uncountably many disjoint non-empty perfect sets.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: To show that $C_A$ is closed, show that each $x\in[0,1)\setminus C_A$ has an open nbhd disjoint from $C_A$. Note that if $x\in[0,1)\setminus C_A$, either there is an $n\in A$ such that $x_n\ne 9$, or there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+\setminus A$ such that $x_n=9$; use that $n$ to find the desired open nbhd of $x$. To show that $C_A$ has no isolated points, show that if $x\in C_A$, and $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, there is a $y\in C_A$ such that $x_k=y_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. (Why does this show that $x$ is not an isolated point of $C_A$?)

As for (b), you’ll want to show that if $A,B\subseteq\Bbb Z^+$, $\Bbb Z^+\setminus A$ and $\Bbb Z^+\setminus B$ are infinite, and $A\ne B$, then $C_A\cap C_B=\varnothing$. You’ll also need to show that $1$ is a limit point of at least one of the sets $C_A$.

Comment: M.Scott: could you please talk more about nbh of x above?

Comment: @user52523: Let’s look at a specific example. Suppose that $3\in A$, and the decimal expansion of $x$ starts $0.2345\ldots$; if $|x-y|<0.0001$, the decimal expansion of $y$ will also start $0.234\ldots$, and $y$ will not be in $C_A$. Thus, we’ve found an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $C_A$.

Comment: M.Scott: So, if $n\in A$ then $|x-y|<10^{-n-2} $with $y=0.x_1x_2x_3...x_nx_{n+1}...$ will not be in $C_A$.

Comment: @user52523: You have to be a little more careful with rational $x$. Suppose that $A=\{1,2,3\}$, and $x=0.99000\ldots$. Then $3\in A$, and $x_3\ne 9$, so $x\notin C_A$. However, in this case no matter how small a nbhd of $x$ you take, it’s going to contain points whose expansions do not start $0.990$: it’s going to contain points whose expansions start $0.98$. This is okay, because these points are not in $C_A$, but what if $A=\{1,3\}$? Then $0.989\in C_A$, for instance. But you can take an even smaller interval around $x$ in which everything has an expansion beginning $0.9899$, and those ...

Comment: ... numbers are *not* in $C_A$. What it boils down to is that you have the right basic idea, but there are some special cases that have to be argued separately.